# Parse query not sorting properly

Tags: android, sorting, parse-platform, number-formatting

I'm pulling images from a Parse dbase. The images are downloading and displaying fine and the filter for Jon works too.
The problem is that they are displaying in the wrong order. I want them to display newest first but they are displaying randomly.
I've tried  .orderByDecending("createdAt") and even added a system timestamp to them when they're uploaded and ordered by that.
nothing seems to work.
The closeest I've got to figuring it out is the fact that when I logged the value I'm using to order by it looks nothing like the value in the parse dashboard. eg in the code below createdAt = 34!

```
 query.whereEqualto("name", "jon")
            .orderByDescending("createdAt")

                .findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {

                        if (e == null) {
                            if (list.size() > 0) {
                                for (final ParseObject object : list) {
                                    ParseFile file = (ParseFile) object.get("imageFile");
                                    file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {

                                            if (e == null) {
                                                Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

                                                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                                                imageView.setImageBitmap(image);
                                                imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

                                                ));


                                                Log.i("info", "object Id " + object.get("objectId"));
                                                Log.i("info", "created At " + object.get("createdAt"));

                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
```

Comment: What happens if you call `getObjectId()` and `getCreatedAt()` instead?  Most or all of the built in columns have special getters.

Comment: they are displaying in the wrong order, means Log.i? "getDataInBackground " seem a non-blocking call, inner done will be called when it finished, so that the log appears not as your expected.

Comment: Thanks nasch, the log is reporting properly now but the query still isn't sorting. Any ideas?

Comment: Dates should be sorted chronologically and the objectId lexicographically. Can you share your data and  show how that is not the case?

Comment: createdAt is generated by Parse. The Parse dashboard reports it is of data type "data" and displays values as date/time.